# Running Multiple Selenium Chrome Profile Simultaneously at the same time

Tags: c#

First, this is not a duplicate question! Read & watch before mark as a duplicate!
This question I ask about open multiple chrome profile using selenium c# and navigate about URL, not duplicate in this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-d)
as you mention, Ok? Shame on your budgets and no help!

You have no Knowledge about Selenium and I don't want your answer to get out of my question ok? DebanjanB

---

I would like to run multiple Selenium Chrome Portable Profile at the same time. I would like to run more than one instance simultaneously.

And using

```
Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.somesite.com");
```

If just one instance of the program is running everything goes fine. If I start a second instance while the first one is running the browser is opened but the automation doesn't start.

This error appears:

> ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
>   OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location D:\GoogleChromePortable\GoogleChromePortable.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Everything is in this video: https://www.useloom.com/share/58725b7fdbb447df86b983107c3b35cf

How can I open multiple chrome profile and each profile open the URL as described in the video!

I'm using C# for selenium, chrome is version 68, `chromedriver 2.41`!
I'm using a custom profile  and a ChromePortable binary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**This is due to same user-data-dir path configured for both instance.** The user-data directory get locked by the first instance and the second instance fails with exception as the directory is in use. The solution is to use two different user-data directory for each driver.

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797350/multithreading-chromedriver-does-not-open-url-in-second-window/52799116#52799116) answer for more details.